# OpenCV features detection and matching - segfault on drawing matches

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, surf, object-detection

Following [this example](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/matcher_simple.cpp),
I'm trying to build an application to recognize objects in a video.
My program is composed of the following steps (see code sample of each step below):

1. Read the image of the object to be recognized into a `cv::Mat` object.
2. Detect keypoints in the object and compute descriptors.
3. Read each frame of the video,
4. Detect keypoints and compute descriptors of the frame,
5. Match the descriptors of the frame to the descriptors of the object,
6. Draw results.

**Problem:** The 6'th step causes a segmentation fault (see code below).
**Question:** What causes it, and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

**Notes:**

1. The program runs for several frames before the segfault. The crash occurs on frame 23, which is the first frame of the video that has any content (i.e. which is not completely black).
2. By removing the line of `drawMatches(...);` there is **no** crash.
3. Running on Windows 7, OpenCV 2.4.2, MinGW.

**Debuggind attempt:**

Running the program through gdb yields the following message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x685585db in _fu156___ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE () from c:\opencv\build\install\bin\libopencv_features2d242.dll
```

**Step 1 - reading object's image:**

```
Mat object;
object = imread(OBJECT_FILE, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

**Step 2 - Detecting keypoints in the object and computing descriptors:**

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(500);
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object;
Mat descriptors_object;
detector.detect(object , keypoints_object);
extractor.compute(object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
```

**Steps 3-6:**

```
VideoCapture capture(VIDEO_FILE);
namedWindow("Output",0);
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2,true);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_frame;
vector<DMatch> matches;
Mat frame,
    output,
    descriptors_frame;

while (true)
{
    //step 3:
    capture >> frame;
    if(frame.empty())
    {
        break;
    }
    cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //step 4:
    detector.detect(frame, keypoints_frame);
    extractor.compute(frame, keypoints_frame, descriptors_frame);

    //step 5:
    matcher.match(descriptors_frame, descriptors_object, matches);

    //step 6:
    drawMatches(object, keypoints_object, frame, keypoints_frame, matches, output);
    imshow("Output", output);
    waitKey(1);
}
```

**Screenshot just before the segfault:**
[image: Screenshot]

**Frame 22 (completely black):**
[image: Frame 22]

**Frame 23 (in which the segfault occurs):**
[image: Frame 23]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with the order of the parameters in `drawMatches`.
The correct order is:

```
drawMatches(frame, keypoints_frame, object, keypoints_object, matches, output);
```

**Explanation:**

In step 5, I'm using the `match` method of the `matcher` object:

```
matcher.match(descriptors_frame, descriptors_object, matches);
```

The [signature of this method](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp#L1108) is

```
void match( const Mat& queryDescriptors, const Mat& trainDescriptors,
            CV_OUT vector<DMatch>& matches, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
```

Which means that `matches` contains matches **from** `trainDescriptors` **to** `queryDescriptors`.
In my case, the train descriptors are of the `object` and the query descriptors are of the `frame`, so `matches` contains matches **from** the `object` **to** the `frame`.

[The signature](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp#L1486) of `drawMatches` is

```
void drawMatches( const Mat& img1, const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints1,
                  const Mat& img2, const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints2,
                  const vector<DMatch>& matches1to2,
                  ... );
```

When calling `drawMatches` with the **incorrect** order of parameters:

```
drawMatches(object, keypoints_object, frame, keypoints_frame, matches, output);
```

the method looks for the coordinates of matches in the incorrect image, which might result in trying to access "out-of-bounds" pixels; Thus the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your prog in a debugger?

Just a guess, drawmatch is segfaulting when there are no matches to draw?? try adding `if (!matches.empty())` before `drawMatches`. By the way, are you sure `matches` is emptied before calling `matcher.matches(...)` ? If not you should do it manually at each loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks you you response. Yes, I did try running the program through a debugger, but since I'm using OpenCV DLL's, I can't step into the library's code. All I know is that the problem is with `drawMatches`. Besides, I doubt it's a problem with the library itself; I assume I'm somehow using it wrong. Also, the problem is not with `matches`, since there are other empty frames in which `matches` is empty, and the problem does not occur. btw, I am emptying the `matches` object each iteration (although I don't think it's really necessary); I just didn't write it here.

Comment: Try compiling OpenCV in debug mode. This should be pretty straightforward using CMake. With minGW, you shoudl generate linux makefiles. But it works also with VC++ 2010 express, did it just last week.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good idea, but the solution was actually much simpler, and I missed it due to lack of attention (see my answer).